# Problem with finding proper regular expression in my solution from Codewars task named Mumbling

Tags: javascript, regex, algorithm

I am looking at the [Mumbling](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5667e8f4e3f572a8f2000039/train/javascript) code challenge on CodeWars:

> The examples below show you how to write function `accum`:
>
> #### Examples:
>
> ```
> accum("abcd") -> "A-Bb-Ccc-Dddd"
> accum("RqaEzty") -> "R-Qq-Aaa-Eeee-Zzzzz-Tttttt-Yyyyyyy"
> accum("cwAt") -> "C-Ww-Aaa-Tttt"
> ```
>
> The parameter of `accum` is a string which includes only letters from `a..z` and `A..Z`.

This is my attempt:

```
function accum(s) {
  const holdArr = [...s];
  const tempArr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < holdArr.length; i++) {
    tempArr.push(holdArr[i].repeat(i + 1).toLowerCase());
  }
  return tempArr.join("-").replace(/(^|-\w)/g, (x) => x.toUpperCase());
}
```

The problem is that within input like:

```
console.log(accum("abCd"));
```

...it gives output: **a-Bb-Ccc-Ddd**, but it should give **A-Bb-Ccc-Dddd**. How can I tune the RegEx to get it?

Comment: Notices: 1) no need to use `toLowerCase()` inside the loop, do it before on the whole string: `const holdArr = [...s.toLowerCase()];`. 2) instead of using a regex replacement at the very end, you can decrease the number of repetitions and add directly the first letter in uppercase: `tempArr.push(holdArr[i].toUpperCase() + holdArr[i].repeat(i));`

Comment: Is an input of "yY" to be handled the same as "yy"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `/(^|-\w)/g`, then the letter will be matched only if it follows an hypen.

You should instead use `/(^|-)\w/g` for matching the letter also when it follows the beginning of the string.

Comment: It's more simple to use `\b\w` as a pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer to the question, but a way to do it without regex:

```
const accum = (s, c = 0) =>
  [...s.toLowerCase()].map((l) => `${l.toUpperCase()}${l.repeat(c++)}`).join('-');

console.log(accum('abcd')); // A-Bb-Ccc-Dddd
```

---

As an aside if you want to find the first word character in a pattern, you can put a *word-boundary* before it: `\b\w`.
It matches after a `-` or a the start of the string.